# HTML table cell goes down when add text

Tags: html

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="rds" cellspacing="15px">
    <tr>
        <td id="r1"><a id="rx1" href="#"></a></td>
        <td id="r2"><a id="rx2" href="#"></a></td>
        <td id="r3"><a id="rx3" href="#"></a></td>
        <td id="r4"><a id="rx4" href="#"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And css file:

```
.rds {
    width: auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.rds tr td a:link, .rds tr td a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 39px;
    height: 39px;
    background-image: url('images/bg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.rds tr td a:active, .rds tr td a:hover {
    display: block;
    width: 39px;
    height: 39px;
    background-image: url('images/bg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

But when I add some text to  tags, all cell goes down a bit. Only cell with text goes down.

What can I do?

Comment: try `vertical-align="top"` on all cells. In css it could look like `td {vertical-align:top;}`

Comment: I don't see your problem [Check This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JHs5/), *I've added background color and outline for demonstration*

Comment: TobSpr. Thanks, now everything is ok.

Comment: @TobSpr Please post your comment as an answer for future users that are willing to guess the answer, like me.. When I'm going to visit this, I knew, I know the answer but it's already solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align="top"` on all cells. In css it could look like

```
td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```